# Excel VBA To Concatenate

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

from some googling I found this function that will concatenate the data in columns A, B & C based off the value in column D.  This code does not work for me for some reason.  My data looks like such

```
Bob   Jason   0123456789  Tim
Jim   Jason   0123456789  Tim
Fred  Jason   0123456789  Tim
```

Columns, A and B concat fine, but column C concats to

```
12,345,678,901,234,500,000,000,000,000
```

How would the VBA be altered so that the code will concatenate properly?

```
Sub Concat()
    Dim x, i As Long, ii As Long
    With Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        x = .Columns("d").Offset(1).Address
        x = Filter(Evaluate("transpose(if(countif(offset(" & x & ",,,row(1:" & .Rows.Count & "))," & x & ")=1," & x & "))"), False, 0)
        For i = 0 To UBound(x)

            For ii = 1 To 3
                Cells(i + 2, ii + 5).Value = Join(Filter(Evaluate("transpose(if(" & .Columns(4).Address & "=""" & _
                    x(i) & """," & .Columns(ii).Address & "))"), False, 0), ",")
            Next
            Cells(i + 2, ii + 5).Value = x(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the destination cells to a Text format:

```
Sub Concat()
    Dim x, i As Long, ii As Long
    With Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        x = .Columns("d").Offset(1).Address
        x = Filter(Evaluate("transpose(if(countif(offset(" & x & ",,,row(1:" & .Rows.Count & "))," & x & ")=1," & x & "))"), False, 0)
        For i = 0 To UBound(x)

            For ii = 1 To 3
                Cells(i + 2, ii + 5).NumberFormat = "@"
                Cells(i + 2, ii + 5).Value = Join(Filter(Evaluate("transpose(if(" & .Columns(4).Address & "=""" & _
                    x(i) & """," & .Columns(ii).Address & "))"), False, 0), ",")
            Next
            Cells(i + 2, ii + 5).NumberFormat = "@"
            Cells(i + 2, ii + 5).Value = x(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```